# Python web scraping - UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I have a code which gets the links from a website. There are few problems. The code generates the correct output when it is run the second time. No output is generated the first time. Second I am getting an error.

Error message:

```
   traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
        exec(codeObject, __main__.__dict__)
      File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\ld.py", line 25, in <module>
        wr.writerows([tag.text])
      File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
        return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x91' in position 410: character maps to <undefined>
```

---

Code:

```
import csv
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.dhr.gov.in/"
urls = [url]
visited = [url]
resultFile = open('t5.csv','w', newline ='')
wr = csv.writer(resultFile, delimiter = ' ')
while len(urls)>0:
    try:
        htmltext = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
    except:
        pass    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
    urls.pop(0)
    for tag in soup.findAll('a', href = True):
        tag['href'] = urllib.parse.urljoin(url,tag['href'])
        if url in tag['href']and tag['href'] not in visited:
            urls.append(tag['href'])
            visited.append(tag['href'])
            print([tag['href']])
            print([tag.text])
            wr.writerows([tag['href']])
            wr.writerows([tag.text])
resultFile.close()
```

Comment: I am using python 3.5. Also would like to know how to set the depth of search.

Comment: error has been solved. it was due to Hindi characters. Added an exception handler. The problem of results getting populated only on running the second time remains.

Comment: Another problem is the file opens in a read only mode. Why is that? I am sorry about asking silly questions. This is the first time I am coding in Python.

Comment: problem of results getting populated the second time also fixed. Had to add buffer option. However, the problem of read only  mode remains.

Comment: read only mode problem also solved. added resultFile.close() again. Sorry for bothering you guys. Got a brain freeze yesterday. A fresh set of eyes did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There're some hacks of how get rid of that. But better use python 3 and the error will disappear by itself.